# How to change texts in columns and then combine 1st row with the column headers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```py
data={'a1':['X1',2,3,4,5],'Unnamed: 02':['Y1',5,6,7,8],'b1':['X2',5,3,7,9],'Unnamed: 05':['Y2',5,8,9,3],'c1':['X3',4,5,7,5],'Unnamed: 07':['Y3',5,8,9,3],'d1':['P',2,4,5,7],'Unnamed: 09':['M',8,4,6,7]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns=df.columns.to_series().mask(lambda x: x.str.startswith('Unnamed')).ffill()
df
```

[image]

There are a few things which I would like to do:

1. Change the rows containing (X1, X2 & X3) into just 'X (vice versa for Y1,Y2,Y3 into 'Y)
2. Combine the existing column header with the row containing X,Y,P,M

The outcome should look like:

1. Change the rows containing (X1, X2 & X3) into just 'X (vice versa for Y1,Y2,Y3 into 'Y)

[image]

2. Combine the existing column header with the row containing X,Y,P,M - **Also note that the 'P' and 'M' completely replaces 'd1' respectively.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```py
import numpy as np
# extract only the letters from first row
first_row = df.iloc[0].str.extract('([A-Z]+)')[0]
# update column names by first_row
# the columns with P and M in it have their names completely replaced
df.columns = np.where(first_row.isin(['P', 'M']), first_row, df.columns + '_' + first_row.values)
# remove first row
df = df.iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can do something like this:

```py
# Transpose data frame and make index to column
df = df.T.reset_index()
# Assign new column, use length of first row as condition
df["column"] = np.where(df[0].str.len() > 1, df["index"].str[:] + "_" + df[0].str[0], df[0].str[0])
df.drop(columns=["index", 0]).set_index("column").T.rename_axis(None, axis=1)

----------------------------------------------------------
    a1_X    a1_Y    b1_X    b1_Y    c1_X    c1_Y    P   M
1   2       5       5       5       4       5       2   8
2   3       6       3       8       5       8       4   4
3   4       7       7       9       7       9       5   6
4   5       8       9       3       5       3       7   7

----------------------------------------------------------
```

It's a more general solution as it uses the length of each row-zero entry as a condition, not the actual values 'P' and 'M'. Thus, it holds for each single character string.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.columns = [x + '_' + y[0] if len(y)>1 else y for x, y in df.iloc[0].reset_index().values]
df = df[1:].reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  a1_X a1_Y b1_X b1_Y c1_X c1_Y  P  M
0    2    5    5    5    4    5  2  8
1    3    6    3    8    5    8  4  4
2    4    7    7    9    7    9  5  6
3    5    8    9    3    5    3  7  7
```